# Get all the text from inside multiple sets of brackets python

Tags: python, list

So I am working on a mad lib project, and I have this string:    "One [time of day], I [past tense verb] out of my [place] and saw [a/an] [noun]!  It then saw me, and started to [verb] away!  Once I finally caught up to it, it then proceeded to [verb].  And that is the end of my [noun]!"

Is there a way to get all the text inside that brackets ([]) into a list?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: I did make an honest attempt.  I didn't think it was necessary to upload what I had tried, as they didn't work.  This isn't some "Show me how to solve this problem", I was legitimately asking how you get text from inside multiple brackets in a string.  The reason I gave the specific string and explained what I was doing was for context.  It would be harder to understand the question if I just said "How do I get the text from inside multiple sets of brackets in a string in python", so I added the context.  I am not upset, I am only trying to understand why you think that it was off topic.

Comment: What do you not understand from the posting guidelines?  We expect you to define your problem and include the attempt you would like us to help you repair.  There are many ways to extract such text already documented on line.  Which did you use, and where are you having trouble with that?

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification!  I will try to be more descriptive in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method should work:

```
string = "One [time of day], I [past tense verb] out of my [place] and saw [a/an] [noun]! It then saw me, and started to [verb] away! Once I finally caught up to it, it then proceeded to [verb]. And that is the end of my [noun]!"

chars = len(string)

bracket_text = []
bracket_opened = False
start_ind = 0

for i in range(chars):
    if bracket_opened:
        if string[i] == ']':
            bracket_text.append(string[start_ind:i])
            bracket_opened = False
    if string[i] == '[':
        bracket_opened = True
        start_ind = i + 1
        
print(bracket_text)
```

Here's a quick explanation:

- look for an opening bracket '[' and once you find the first one, remember the index of the character after it using start_ind (the first character of the text in the brackets). You also remember that you've now found an opening bracket using the bracket_opened variable.
- After you know a bracket has been opened, you search for the next closing bracket.
- Once you find the closing bracket, you just pull out the text between its' index and the index of the first character in those brackets that you saved earlier and add it to your list, called bracket_text in this case
- After you've found a closing bracket, you reset the bracket_opened to False and start looking for the next opening bracket.